# If in Java , not a statement error

Tags: java, if-statement

```
class Box
{
// Instance Variables
double length ,ipsos ;
double width ,mikos ;
double height ,platos;
// Constructors
 public Box ( double side )
{
width = side ;
height = side ;
length = side ;
}
public Box ( double x , double y , double z)
{
    platos = y ;
ipsos = z;
mikos = x ;

}

// Methods
double calculate(double praksi)
{
return 2 * ( width * height +
width * length +
height * length ) ;
}
double volume(double emvadon)
{
return platos*ipsos*mikos ;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Volume: " + volume(1) + "\n Calculate: " + calculate(1);
}
public class Cube extends Box {
    public Cube(double side) {
        super(side, side, side);
        if (side<0) { System.out,println("lathos timi);} 
    }
}

}
```

in the upper code,compiler finds an error on this :  if (side<0) { System.out,println("lathos timi);}

it says : not statement

what is wrong?
Im new at java programming , but now about 'if' from C .

Comment: Your code looks like a dogs breakfast.  If you want people to take time to read it, you need to take time to indent it properly.  (Don't bother now, 'cos I expect this Question is going to be closed shortly.  But **for next time** ...)

Comment: one question.. If I run this program , it won't ask to give a value, right? 
By the way i run it in BlueJ. So when i compile and run it , it creats a box and i put some values in the blank boxes, but it does nothing. Is it something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You have a comma in your println statement. It should be:

```
System.out.println("lathos timi");
```

Comment: if you are an idiot for that then so is everyone else :-)

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make :) Whenever I'm learning anything new I'll assume all bugs are due to me not understanding the new thing I'm trying to learn, I totally forget to check the basics!

Comment: one question.. If I run this program , it won't ask to give a value, right? By the way i run it in BlueJ. So when i compile and run it , it creats a box and i put some values in the blank boxes, but it does nothing. Is it something wrong?

Comment: This is just a class definition, there's nothing in here instantiating or running it. I haven't used BlueJ before but I assume it has some sort of testing tool that's creating a dialog based on the constructor's arguments.